# Text Color Changes as it Passes over a Section

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to achieve an effect where my header text is fixed and as it scrolls over a section that has an image will appear white, otherwise it will be black.

The effect will be most pronounced as it splits either side of a section with an image.

[image: Picture]

I've tried using [mix blend mode](https://www.kodingkitty.com/blog/blend-modes/), but gotten uneven results. For one, the text overlapping the image isn't a solid color, it'll take on the variation in the image underlying it.

Comment: Please provide a minimum example of what you did so we can help you

Comment: I think you can use [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) in css to achieve it.